# Python 32-bit can't find MySQLdb module on OS X Lion

Tags: python, mysql, osx-lion, mysql-python

I've been tearing my hair out and trying the solutions to getting Python and MySQL to play nicely with 64-bit architecture, and the solution seems to have all components installed/run as 32-bit.

My issue is that for some reason, running Python in 32-bit mode via 
$ arch -i386 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

and then

> > > import MySQLdb

gives me

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

However, when I run python in 64-bit mode and trying 'import MySQLdb' I get the dreaded:

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in 
> > >         File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in 
> > >         File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in **bootstrap**
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
> > >               /Users/me/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

So my question is, why can't Python find the module in 32-bit mode?  the "wrong architecture" error leads me to believe that MySQL-python is installed as 32-bit, so I don't think it's that 32-bit Python can't "see" the module.  I have both the python and the .python-eggs path on my $PATH in .bash_profile, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, but have you tried just to `pip install MySQL-python`? If you have some `mysql_config` in your path, it should compile just fine.

– I am using a Python 2.7.2 via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), a [MAMP 2.0](https://www.mamp.info/en/mac/) installation, running on 10.6. with a [64bit](https://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html) kernel.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I tried the homebrew solution when I was going for "everything 64-bit" but I kept getting gcc-4.0 not found errors... I have Xcode 4.1 installed, which as I understand is supposed to be used by homebrew instead of gcc to compile, but it didn't work for me.  Maybe it's related to 10.7?  Anyway, thanks again!